# Jquery - insert html snippet and slidedown

Tags: jquery, slidedown

This is not wanting to work for some reason.  I'm simply trying to have some `html` inserted and slid down into a `div` when a link is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/mT9mc/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your CSS.

```
div {
    background: #eee;
    display:none; //add display:none;
}
```

The reason it wasn't sliding down before, was it was already visible.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mT9mc/6/

Comment: Thanks for that. Knew it had to be something simple

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I was going to say the same as ahren, the div is already visible, so you cannot use `slideDown` on an already visible element. You can either add `display: none;` to the div's style or you can use the following...

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('div').hide().html('ffasdf').slideDown('slow');
});
```

As [shown in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4nmdr/)

Answer (score 2):

Your div has to be hidden for it to actually slide down

see http://jsfiddle.net/mT9mc/4/

Answer (score 1):

the "div" tag has to be hidden with `display: none` ;)

add that to the css and your code should work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mT9mc/7/)